# all things are replacing except of Question Mark '?' ,using replace()

Tags: javascript

i m using simple javascript to replace things like:

- '.' with 'Dot' .
- and  '<' with 'lessThan' .

but when i try to replace the Question mark ,its not working , even all things is not replacing if i use '?' in my string.

here is JSfiddle of working http://jsfiddle.net/2w5oLcpz/    ... // without ? mark in string

not working jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/b05y0f5q/  ....   //using ? in string

here is code sample://not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var a0 = ".,!,<,>,?";
    var a = a0.split(','); //+ a000.split(',');

    var b0 = "Dot,exclMark,LessThan,GreatThan,Qmark"
    var b = b0.split(','); //+ b000.split(','); 

    var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
    for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
              str = str.replace(new RegExp(a[k].replace(/\./g, '\\.'),"g"), b[k]);

    };
    document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
     }
   </script>

<body >

<textarea onkeyup="myFunction(); "  id="textBox1" placeholder="Type Here" ></textarea>
<TEXTAREA type="text" id="textBox2"  ></TEXTAREA>

</body>
```

please answer in js  ,im not familiar with Jquery.

Comment: Try with this in for loop str = str.replace(a[k],b[k]); if this works let me know

Comment: i tried this one, it will replace it , but only one time . means when i type "<<<<" it returns "lessthan<<<"

Comment: Ok try the answers which gave they worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nakul,
Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2w5oLcpz/4/) for a working version.  You did not escape the ? which is a special character in a regular expression.  This is done by prefixing it with \.  So it should have been \? instead of ? in your string.  Here is a working version of the code you uploaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {


    var a0 = ".,!,<,>,?";
    var a = a0.split(','); //+ a000.split(',');


    var b0 = "Dot,exclMark,LessThan,GreatThan,Qmark"
    var b = b0.split(','); //+ b000.split(','); 
  
    var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
    for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
              str = str.replace(new RegExp(a[k].replace(/\./g, '\\.'),"g"), b[k]);

    };
    document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
     }


</script>



<body >

<textarea onkeyup="myFunction(); "  id="textBox1" placeholder="Type Here" ></textarea>
<TEXTAREA type="text" id="textBox2"  ></TEXTAREA>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit slower on typing because I wanted to explain what the problem was rather than just giving you an answer.  All is good though.

Comment: hey @davan can i ask you a thing, what if want to replace "?!" with "mixdTtped" ,, here "\\?\\!" is not working"...

Comment: Nakul, please refer to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2w5oLcpz/5/ for an example with that working.  You need to have \\?! at the beginning of the string because otherwise it will be replaced with the other options before it hits that one since it is more complex.

Comment: It is no problem Nakul.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b05y0f5q/1/)
You need to use `\\?` instead of `?`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {


    var a0 = ".,!,<,>,\\?";
    var a = a0.split(','); //+ a000.split(',');


    var b0 = "Dot,exclMark,LessThan,GreatThan,Qmark"
    var b = b0.split(','); //+ b000.split(','); 
  
    var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
    for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
              str = str.replace(new RegExp(a[k].replace(/\./g, '\\.'),"g"), b[k]);

    };
    document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
     }


</script>



<body >

<textarea onkeyup="myFunction(); "  id="textBox1" placeholder="Type Here" ></textarea>
<TEXTAREA type="text" id="textBox2"  ></TEXTAREA>
  
</body>
```

Comment: can you tell me why this is happening , and why mine not working.

Comment: You have not written like "var a0 = ".,!,<,>,\\?";" you have written "var a0 = ".,!,<,>,?";" that's why it was not working

Comment: @Nakul It's not working because just like `.`, the `?` character is a special character and has a meaning of its own (other than being a question mark) in regular expressions. So, just like you did for the `.`, you need to escape it.

Comment: what if want to replace "?!" with "mixdTtped" ,, here "\\?\\!" is not working"...